# How to get image position with Google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a Google Doc related add on and wonder if there is a way to get image position from Google Doc with Apps Script?

I checked position class and positionedImage, however, I'm looking for a way to return the offset base on the whole page not the relative position to its parent or anchored paragraph.

For example, if there is an image in page 1, I want the topOffset and leftOffset from the left corner of that page. Is there a way to do this?

Please see image attached below, red part is what I'm looking for. When using positionedImage.getTopOffset() or positionedImage.getLeftOffset() it would only return the offset based on the most closet paragraph not the absolute offset based on the page.

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fphq.png)

Many thanks!

Comment: I think there's only the [getLeftOffset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-image#getleftoffset) and [getTopOffset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-image#gettopoffset) under ClassPosition class. Try to file a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @noogui! I just updated my question with an example image, hopefully there is a way to do that...